# object has no attribute 'assertEqual'

Tags: python, selenium

Getting  object has no attribute 'assertEqual' when I try to use the below statement in my code:

```
self.assertEqual("IRELAND INSTITUTE OF PITTSBURGH", driver.find_element_by_id("cname").get_attribute("value"))
```

This works fine when I use in my test case instead. I understand that it is a good practice to put asserts in the test case. But I would like to understand why this piece of code cannot work in the page instead if we are following page object pattern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`assertEqual` is a method that belongs to the class `TestCase` from the unittest module ([python unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual)).

The reason it works in your test code is most likely because you test class inherits from the `TestCase` class.

```
class YourTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    pass
```

You could just use the keyword `assert`:

```
assert "IRELAND INSTITUTE OF PITTSBURGH" == driver.find_element_by_id("cname").get_attribute("value")
```

If the assertion fails, it will raise an [AssertionError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.AssertionError).