# Cannot test a raise Exception function

Tags: python, exception

I would like to test that my function raises an Exception when trying to open a file that does not exist.

Here is my code for the function

```
import os

def open_files(path_1, path_2):

    """Raises an Exception in case a file
    does not exists."""

    can_open_1 = os.path.exists(path_1)
    can_open_2 = os.path.exists(path_2)

    if can_open_1 or can_open_2 == False:
        raise Exception("Files do not exist")
```

and here for the test:

```
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
import open_files


class TestOpenFiles(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_open_files(self):

        some_cool_exception = Exception("Files do not exist")
        self.assertRaises(some_cool_exception, open_files.open_files("maracana.tif", "carlitos.tif"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I read that post: 
[object has no attribute 'assertEqual'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859577/object-has-no-attribute-assertequal)
and I implemented the way that Exceptions can be tested using the unittest module in Python. 
I don't know why I still receive this error message when running the test via

```
python -m unittest test_open_files
```

Error:

```
test_open_files (test_open_files.TestOpenFiles) ... ERROR

---------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Share\__Python_Development\88_Cloud_Detection\test_open_files.py", line 12, in test_open_files self.assertRaises(some_cool_exception, open_files.open_files("maracana.tif", "carlitos.tif")) 
    File "D:\Share\__Python_Development\88_Cloud_Detection\open_files.py", line 12, in open_files
    raise Exception("Files do not exist")
Exception: Files do not exist

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.0000x

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I cannot get information from the test run, which could help me to figure out to set a correct test for an exception.

Comment: `can_open_1 or can_open_2 == False` seems wrong to me concerning `can_open_1`. You probably meant to say `can_open_1 == False or can_open_2 == False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was here:

```py
if can_open_1 or can_open_2 == False:
    raise Exception("Files do not exist")
```

The interpreter would not interpret this as one of the following correct options:

#### Method-1

```py
if (can_open_1==False) or (can_open_2==False):
    raise Exception("Files do not exist")
```

I would also suggest to use parentheses to explicitly specify which conditions grouped together.

#### Method-2

You could have also written it as follows:

```py
if (not can_open_1) or (not can_open_2):
    raise Exception("Files do not exist")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved the problem. I didn't take care of the correct comparison syntax for test my exception raise.

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition is wrong, your condition check if can_open_1 is true and raise an exception:

```
if can_open_1 == False or can_open_2 == False:
    raise Exception("Files do not exist")
```

For Example,

```
can_open_1=True
can_open_2=True

if can_open_1 or can_open_2==False:
   print("something is wrong") 
# prints something is wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if can_open_1 or can_open_2 == False:
```

it means either `can_open_1` is `True`  or  `can_open_2` is `False`

from your code, you may meant to say

```
can_open_1 == False or  can_open_2 == False
```